# Sorting files by name

Tags: 14.04, filemanager, filename, file-sorting

Is there a way I can change the way files are currently "sorted by name", to include common non-alphabetical characters like `+-_`?

I don't mind getting my hands dirty if someone can point me to the script that's responsible for sorting the files (probably a python script?).

---

@muru helpfully pointed to [this function](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus/blob/master/libnautilus-private/nautilus-column-utilities.c#L295) as being responsible for sorting filenames in Nautilus' sources. I can't see anything wrong with it given that it uses `strcmp`, so maybe the problem happens before that because of some string sanitization?

To be clear with the question: I would expect the order `{"_name 1", "_name 3", "name 2"}` but Nautilus currently sorts these names as `{"_name 1", "name 2", "_name 3"}`.

Comment: The Nautlis source code seems to be [mostly C](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus/tree/master/src).

Comment: Well I could do with C, but recompiling Nautilus brings the amount of work to a level I didn't expect. It might be easier to just change the file manager altogether :(

Comment: @Tim I was thinking more like [https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus/blob/master/libnautilus-private/nautilus-column-utilities.c#L295](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus/blob/master/libnautilus-private/nautilus-column-utilities.c#L295).

Comment: @muru yep, that's it.

Comment: Yeah it seems the function I'm looking for is `g_list_sort_with_data`

Comment: @Sh3ljohn That's [a library function](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html#g-list-sort-with-data) that takes a comparison function as parameter - the one I linked to.

Comment: What order are you expecting exactly? have you tried just invoking nautilus with a C collation locale? e.g. `LC_COLLATE=C nautilus somedir` (if nautilus is already running, you will need to kill it first)

Comment: @steeldriver interesting. The order for `a+b`, `a-b` and `a_c` when I run it normally (`LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8`) is the reverse of when it's run with `LC_COLLATE=C`.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Yep, that behaviour can be fixed by setting `LC_COLLATE=C`.  You will see its effect on a lot of other places - even a simple `ls` would show `_name3` after `name2` depending on `LC_COLLATE`.

Comment: @steeldriver Impressive! Thanks a lot I just tried and it fixed the problem! You should post a short answer :) Is there a way I can make this permanent?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn edit `/etc/default/locale` to set it system wide, or create a file called `.pam_environment` in your home directory containing `LC_COLLATE=C` to affect just your user.